# unable to obtain isolated JDBC connection Spring Boot + JPA

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am getting the above error when i try to do something with my database, which is not flyway or a simple select.

```
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
unable to obtain isolated JDBC connection; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: unable to obtain isolated JDBC connection
org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: unable to obtain isolated JDBC connection; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: unable to obtain isolated JDBC connection
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:255)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:233)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:551)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:61)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:242)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:152)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:174)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215)
    at jdk.proxy3/jdk.proxy3.$Proxy91.saveAll(Unknown Source)
```

POMDependecies

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
            <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.modelmapper</groupId>
            <artifactId>modelmapper</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mariadb.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>mariadb-java-client</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.12.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0-2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.12.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mchange</groupId>
            <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.5.5</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
```

application.properties

```
spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=20MB
spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size=20MB
spring.datasource.hikari.maximum-pool-size=10
spring.datasource.hikari.connectionTimeout=30000   
spring.datasource.hikari.idleTimeout=600000          
spring.datasource.hikari.maxLifetime=1800000  
hibernate.c3p0.min_size=5
hibernate.c3p0.max_size=20
hibernate.c3p0.timeout=300
hibernate.c3p0.max_statements=50
hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period=3000
logging.level.com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig=DEBUG 
logging.level.com.zaxxer.hikari=TRACE
```

In addition i sometimes get

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [de/ak/mkm/config/PersistenceJPAConfig.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to open JDBC Connection for DDL execution
Caused by: java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Socket fail to connect to host:localhost, port:3306. Address already in use: no further information
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: no further information
```

on the startup of the application.

And when i shutdown the app it throws an error, because it somehow tries to create an entityManager.

```
package de.test.config;


import org.springframework.cache.annotation.EnableCaching;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaVendorAdapter;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

import javax.sql.DataSource;
import java.util.Properties;


@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableCaching
public class PersistenceJPAConfig{

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource(){
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver");
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/DB?autoReconnect=true");
        dataSource.setUsername( "XXXX" );
        dataSource.setPassword( "XXXXXXXX" );
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        em.setDataSource(dataSource());
        em.setPackagesToScan("de.test.jpa.model");

        JpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        em.setJpaProperties(additionalProperties());

        return em;
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory().getObject());

        return transactionManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor exceptionTranslation(){
        return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
    }

    public Properties additionalProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "create-drop");
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect");
        properties.setProperty("spring.datasource.hikari.maximum-pool-size", "10");
        properties.setProperty("spring.datasource.hikari.connectionTimeout", "30000");
        properties.setProperty("spring.datasource.hikari.idleTimeout", "600000");
        properties.setProperty("spring.datasource.hikari.maxLifetime", "1800000");
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.c3p0.min_size", "5");
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.c3p0.max_size", "20");
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.c3p0.timeout", "300");
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.c3p0.max_statements", "50");
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period", "3000");
        return properties;
    }
}
```

I don't think the config is working.

Comment: It seems the problem was caused by properties.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "create-drop");. I changed that to auto and now the problem did not appear again.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the problem was caused by properties.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "create-drop");. I changed that to auto and now the problem did not appear again.